# not to mention and let alone

Tags: synonyms

"Let alone" is often treated as a synonym of "not to mention." But are they interchangeable? Are the following sentences correct? If only #1 and #2 are correct, what's their difference?

1. John can speak Classical Greek, Latin, French, and Japanese, not to mention English.
2. John can speak English, not to mention Classical Greek, Latin, French, and Japanese.
3. John can speak English, let alone  Classical Greek, Latin, French, and Japanese.
4. John can speak  Classical Greek, Latin, French, and Japanese, let alone English. (This one is definitely wrong; added here for contrastive purposes.)

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: #3 and #4 are not idiomatic.On what grounds do you understand them  to be different?

Comment: The very fact that "not to mention" works in the same sentences where "let alone" doesn't makes the two different.

Comment: I'm curious about the difference between #1 and #2.

Comment: You implied that 3 and 4 were different *from each other*. I'm asking you why you think so, not alleging a difference.

Comment: I found this Google ngram of the two phrases interesting: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let+alone%2Cnot+to+mention&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clet%20alone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blet%20alone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLet%20alone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnot%20to%20mention%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnot%20to%20mention%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20to%20mention%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Well, I suspected 3 is incorrect, too. On the scale of obscurity, English is the lesser whereas the others are the greater. But the other requirement, which we didn't discuss yesterday, crossed my mind, i.e. the implicational requirement. For "let alone" to work, there must be an inference from the lesser to the greater.

Comment: For example, in the sentence "His erratic driving had given the police probable cause to search the vehicle, let alone the fact that his passenger was bound and gagged," we can surmise that if erratic driving warrants a police search, then having a passenger bound and gagged does, too. But no such implication holds for #3. If John can speak English, we cannot surmise that he can speak Classical Greek, Latin, etc.

Comment: Both "not to mention" and "let alone" are rhetorically relatively informal (especially "let alone"), and as long as you have a good sense of when to use them (which you seem to do), an in-depth analysis probably isn't warranted.

Comment: @Apollyon: This pattern does not involve **surmise**. It involves a scale (one of the items being the lesser of the two, the other item the greater) *a scale which both speaker and listener understand to be in effect in the given context*.   Erratic driving is the lesser offense; having a passenger trussed up and gagged is the greater offense. But the lesser offense suffices to give the police probable cause; the greater offense need not be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

**not to mention** is used in situations where an already impressive fact  is augmented, in (feigned) afterthought, with a yet more impressive fact.

> The house has two tennis courts, a five-car garage, and an
>   Olympic-size swimming pool, not to mention access to a private beach.
>
> The house has two tennis courts, not to mention a five-car garage,  an Olympic-sized swimming pool, and access to a private beach.
>
> She has volunteered at the library and at a local soup kitchen serving the homeless, not to mention the hundreds of hours she has devoted to the town as chair of the recycling committee for the last eight years.

As discussed in a similar question you asked recently,  **let alone** is used in situations where the lesser of two items (in a given context) has already met or exceeded a threshold, so that there is no need to invoke the greater one.

> His erratic driving had given the police probable cause to search the vehicle, let alone the fact that his passenger was bound and gagged.
>
> We have no need for another car, let alone no place to park it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67242/discussion-on-answer-by-tomauo-not-to-mention-and-let-alone).